# Parse a number from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

i have string like those `/ 5` or `/ 91` or `/ 358`. I need to get the integers after last space from those strings. Here is how I do it know but it only can get one number. How to make it?

`f_quantity = f_quantity.substr(f_quantity.length - 1);`

Comment: try `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Comment: @karim79 There is space before `/` too :P

Comment: parseInt(f_quantity.split("/")[1],10)  then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example you can validate in a web console:

```
console.log( (' / 358').match("[0-9]+") );
```

So...

```
f_quantity = (' / 358').match("[0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is space before the last number you can write the following:

```js
string val = ' / 5' or ' / 91' or ' / 358'. 
var arr = val.split(' ');
arr[val.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this that will get you the number:

```
var s = " / 91";
var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
var num = s.match(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the string always of the format ' / NUM'? If so, use this to get the string of the number:

```
f_quantity = f_quantity.substr(3, f_quantity.length);
```

And then this to turn it into an actual number:

```
f_quantity = parseInt(f_quantity);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
f_quantity = parseInt(f_quantity.substr(3, f_quantity.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the last integer value preceded by a space, allowing for additional white space at the end:

```
f_quantity = ~~f_quantity.match( /\s+\d+\s*$/ )
```